# What kind of "measure" is $dB_{t}(\omega)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In stochastic integration one considers integrals as $L^2(P)$ limits of simple functions w.r.t  $dB_{t}(\omega)$ where $B$ is standard brownian motion.

It is not clear to me what kind of object this $ dB_{t}(\omega)$ is, it is certaintly not a measure in the usual sense. How should one think about this object? And is there a name for it in general?

Comment: The idea is to consider $\int f_t d(B (t,\omega) )$ as a generalisation of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral indexed by the $\omega$ in the probability space, only of course $B_t$ is not of bounded variation and so more work has to be done - the resulting construction is I think pretty unanimously known as the Ito integral, and so $dB_t(\omega)$ is the integrator of the Ito integral.

Comment: @Nadiels right, but these kind of object has no name in general?

Comment: For the Riemann-Stieltjes integral the term $d g(x)$ often gets referred to as the integrator, so I would be reasonably happy to refer to $dB_t(\omega)$ as the integrator of the Ito-integral, I'm afraid I don't know if there is a more universally accepted name though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a measure in the usual sense, but in a *probabilistic sense*.

Specifically, let $\mathcal B_f(\mathbb{R})$ denote the family of Borel sets having finite Lebesgue measure.

> An *independently scattered Gaussian measure* (with Lebesgue control measure) is a random set function $$\{B(A,\omega),A\in \mathcal B_f(\mathbb{R}), \omega\in \Omega\}$$ (you can understand this a $\mathcal B_f(\mathbb{R})$-indexed stochastic process) such that
>
> - for any $A\in \mathcal B_f(\mathbb{R})$, $B(A)$ is a centered Gaussian random variable with variance $\lambda(A)$;
> - for any disjoint $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n \in \mathcal B_f(\mathbb{R})$, the random variables $B(A_1),B(A_2),\dots,B(A_n)$ are independent;
> - for any disjoint $A_1,A_2,\ldots \in \mathcal B_f(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in \mathcal B_f(\mathbb{R})$,
>     $$
>   B\biggl(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\biggr) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B(A_n)\quad \text{ a.s.}
>   $$

Using it, you can define various objects like

- Wiener process (Brownian motion) $B_t = B([0,t])$;
- stochastic integral etc.

However, here are some important remarks.

1. In the Gaussian case, the independence is equivalent to orthogonality, and the almost sure convergence of a series with independent terms is equivalent (thanks to the Kolmogorov three series theorem) to the mean-square convergence. So any reference on measures with orthogonal increments will do.
2. Despite the $\sigma$-additivity is in almost-sure sense, the exceptional set depends on the particular sequence of sets. And there is no version of $B$ which is a signed measure for almost all $\omega$, so it is not possible to define the integral w.r.t. $B$ as that w.r.t. a signed measure; it can just be defined in the mean-square sense (you should know this already).

Comment: Nice ! You know a good reference for this approch?

Comment: @user1, see the updated answer.