# Is there a measure theoretic interpretation of rough path integrals?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, stochastic-analysis, rough-path-theory

In case of an almost surely continuous function $f$ we know that the Lebesgue Measure coincides with the Riemann Integral.

With this in mind, supposing $\mathbf{X}$ is a rough path lift of $X$, is there some measure $\Lambda_\mathbf{X}$ such that
$$\int_0^t f(X_s) d\mathbf{X}_s = \int_0^t f(X_s) d\Lambda_\mathbf{X}(s)$$
where the left hand side integral is the rough path integral of a finite $p$-variation path with $p \in (2,3]$?

If so, what is a possibile construction of $\Lambda_X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear there is no universal measure $\Lambda$ that can represent any given rough path.

A better analogy is with Riemann-Stieltjes integrals or even better [Young integrals](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/12/25/lecture-7-youngs-integral/) $\int f dg$ with $f\in C^{p},g\in C^{q}$ with $p+q>1$ (since after all Rough paths are a generalization of them).

Here the measure is the [total-variation measure $dg$](https://web.sgh.waw.pl/%7Erlocho/PathStochInt.pdf)

However, generally for rough paths there is not measure necessarily. For example for Itô integrals (which are part of the rough-path framework), we have that $dB_{t}(\omega)$ is not a regular measure see [What kind of "measure" is $dB_{t}(\omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445646/what-kind-of-measure-is-db-t-omega)
because the  Itô integrals  are interpreted as $L^{2}$-limits (since B has infinite first variation).

Comment: Sorry, but shouldn't Rough path integration of the Ito lift of a Brownian motion not be the same of Ito's integral? the first is defined pathwise a.e., the latter as a $L^2$ limit. I understand that there's no general measure for any noise (that would be impossible), I wondered whether there was a construction of $\Lambda$ based knowing $\mathbf{X}$ (I edited the question to account for this).

Comment: see chapter 3 and 5 in Hairer-Friz where they discuss that some Rough-path lifts of Brownian motion include Itô and Stratonovich.